# If$(a,b)=m$, then $(a^i,b^i)=m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If for some suitable positive integers $a,b,m, (a,b)=m$, then $\forall i \in \mathbb{Z+},
> (a^i,b^i)=m$

Please vet the proof.
Let, for some suitable integers k,l, $a=km, b=lm$. Then $a^i=k^im^i, b^i = l^im^i$.

So, still the $\gcd$ of $(k^im^i,l^im^i)$ is $m$, as $(k,l)=1 \implies(k^i,l^i)=1$.

--
Change in proof due to comments:

So, still the $\gcd$ of $(k^im^i,l^im^i)$ is the highest power of $m$, i.e. $m^i$ as $(k,l)=1 \implies(k^i,l^i)=1$.

Comment: It looks to me like the gcd is $m^i$. For instance, $(4,6)=2$ and $(16,36)=4$.

Comment: @carmichael561 $(2,6)=2$, $(2^4,6^4) = (16, 1296)=16=2^4$. So, you are correct. But, proving requires cases, so any algebraic proof will be better.

Comment: Writing $a=km$ and $b=lm$ with $(k,l)=1$ is a good approach, it's just that your conclusion in the last line is incorrect.

Comment: As previous commenst suggest if you note that you make the statement "gcd of $(k^im^i, l^i,m^i)$ is $m$, however, we can see that $m^i \geq m$ will still divide both terms

Comment: I'm not sure you want $i \in \mathbb Z$. What is $\gcd(2^{-1},4^{-1}) = \gcd(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4})$? I think you need $i \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: @FlybyNight Will positive integers not be better, as $i=0$ need not be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a=p_1^{\alpha_1}\ldots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ and $b=p_1^{\beta_1}\ldots p_k^{\beta_k}$, then $(a,b)=p_1^{\min\{\alpha_1,\beta_1\}}\ldots p_k^{\min\{\alpha_k,\beta_k\}}$

What then, can you say about $(a^i,b^i)$?

Hint: $\min\{rx,ry\}=r\min\{x,y\}$ for all $r>0$.

Comment: Then, $a^i=p_1^{\alpha_1^i}\ldots p_k^{\alpha_k^i}$ and $b=p_1^{\alpha_1^i}\ldots p_k^{\alpha_k^i}$, so : $(a^i,b^i) = p_1^{imin\{\alpha_1, \beta_1\}}\ldots p_k^{imin\{\alpha_k, \beta_k\}}$

Comment: @jitender Not quite. Remember that $\left(x^y\right)^z = x^{yz}$ not $x^{y^z}$, so 

$$a^i = p_1^{i\alpha_1}\ldots p_k^{i\alpha_k}$$

You're absolutely right that

$$(a^i,b^i) = p_1^{i\min\{\alpha_1,\beta_1\}}\ldots p_k^{i\min\{\alpha_k,\beta_k\}}$$

The key is that 

$$ p_1^{i\min\{\alpha_1,\beta_1\}}\ldots p_k^{i\min\{\alpha_k,\beta_k\}} = \left( p_1^{\min\{\alpha_1,\beta_1\}}\ldots p_k^{\min\{\alpha_k,\beta_k\}}\right)^i$$

So $(a^i,b^i) = (a,b)^i$, where $i \in \mathbb N$.